# Python accepting list variable but not list from file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am attempting to implement selenium and list.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

pool_size = 1

def worker(item1):
    try:
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Processing:", item1)
        #driver.get(item1)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error | ' + str(e))

pool = Pool(pool_size)

items = open('file.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()

for item in items:
    print(item)
    pool.apply_async(worker, str(item))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

If change `items = open('file.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()` to `items = ['1','2']` it works else, it will just return nothing and end the script. Same thing for the file, if I input 1\n2
No idea why this is happening, super weird. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesn't answer your question, but wouldn't it be easier to use `file.readlines()` and iterate over that?

Comment: …or simply `for item in open('file.txt', 'r'):`.

Comment: Please share the contents of the `file.txt` file. The problem is probably there.

Comment: are items empty list?

Comment: File.txt contents are urls, anything should work @SakibHasan

Comment: @NikolayTsvetanov nah if I print the list after a file read it outputs what was in the txt file

Comment: Do you enter in for loop ? Has `print(item) ` executed ? If so the problem is in worker function, probably you should return driver

Comment: @NikolayTsvetanov yes print(item) executed correctly. Returning driver does nothing, if I use “1” in the list it loads selenium then gives error since 1 isn’t a valid URL

Comment: See how works pool.apply_async function